# Can't play sound files

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, redux, howler.js

Trying to play sound files using https://github.com/joshwcomeau/redux-sounds but I can't get it working. Below is the relevant code I used to set it up. I don't know if webpack isn't loading them correctly or something else. How would I know if they are being loaded properly? Any ideas on how to get this to work? No console errors aside from chrome saying it can't decode the audio, but that is apparently and bug and doesn't present when I try it in Firefox.

**configureStore.js**

```
//...
import soundsMiddleware from 'redux-sounds';
const soundsData = {
  barks: {
    urls: ['data/barkSprite.wav', 'data/barkSprite.mp3'],
    sprite: {
      shortBark: [0, 500],
      longBark: [600, 1250]
    }
  }
};
const loadedSoundsMiddleware = soundsMiddleware(soundsData);
//...
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk, router, logger, loadedSoundsMiddleware),
      DevTools.instrument(),
      persistState(
        window.location.href.match(
          /[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/
        )
      )
    )
  );
//...
```

**actions.js**

```
export const SHORT_BARK = 'SHORT_BARK';
export function shortBark() {
  return {
    type: SHORT_BARK,
    meta: { sound: 'barks.shortBark' }
  };
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.mp3'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.mp3$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Check your network tab in the Chrome inspector - are there any errored URLs trying to load sounds? Also you're not actually using webpack here, webpack means you `require()` the file like any other Javascript file, like `require('../relative/path/to/data/barkSprite.wav')`. Further reading: http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to show the files to express.

```
app.use('/data', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/src/data')));
```